# Python multiprocessing unexpected high memory usage

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork

In our system we have started to experience problems with a task that was working ok, but now it seems to be hanging and uses a high amount of memory (so other tasks fail and raise MemoryError).

Context: example code below had no problem, but for a new database *huge_dataframe* became a lot bigger. The question is that if I run both parts separately it works. But running all together in *process_data_task* will lead to the problem. Running under Python 2.7 on Linux.

I suspect that is something with fork(), but how could each sub-process take so much memory? *huge_dataframe* is deleted before starting multiprocessing. Also is strange that *do_recalculations* hangs only when is called inside *process_data_task* (child not joining?), but it doesn't throw any exception. Any explanation or idea for troubleshooting?

```
def process_data_task():
    # part 1, high memory usage
    huge_dataframe = retrieve_data()
    process_table(huge_dataframe)

    # added this trying to fix the problem but it didn't help
    del huge_dataframe
    gc.collect()

    # part 2, heavy CPU usage, multiprocessing
    do_recalculations()  # recalculate items in parallel

# Multiprocessing done here
def do_recalculations():
     processes = cpu_count()
     items_to_update = [...]  # query database
     work_total_list = chunkify(items_to_update, processes)
     p = Pool(processes)
     result = p.map(sub_process_func, work_total_list)
     p.close()
     p.join()
```

Comment: Can you try gc.collect(2)? it might find more objects (even though it takes a bit more time)

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it didn't help